# Microsoft Azure Functions App - Configure with Code First : Unable to create an object of type DbContext

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create a boilerplate application using [Microsoft Azure Functions App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview). For the app's DB section, I like to use EF Core with code-first support.

I am using these ***NuGet*** packages-
[image]

The **local.settings.json** file is like this-

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "test": "123"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TRY_CXN_String": "Server=localhost;Database=try;User Id=abrar;Password=123;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  }
}
```

Then in the **startup.cs** file is like this-

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        _config = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        ...............
        ...............
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TryDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("TRY_CXN_String")));

        ........
        ........
    }
}
```

And the `DBContext` is like this-

```
public class TryDbContext : DbContext
{
    .........
    .........

    public TryDbContext(DbContextOptions<TryDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    .........
    .........
}
```

When we are trying to run the migration, we are getting this error-

> `Unable to create an object of type 'TryDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`

Can anyone please help, why this kind of error can happen in the Azure function app if we like to use them with the code-first approach?

Comment: Please check your dependency injection Middleware once.Have you added  `addtransient` and `addscoped` in the Middleware?

Comment: Yes, we have configured that. It is shown in the question, `ConfigureServices` section.

Comment: Can you share your code repo?

Comment: It is a private repo, so I can't share it. I have shared the code snippet in the question. If you need anything specific, I can share that along with the code as well.

Comment: What is the version of your App?

Answer (score 0):

***Migration in Azure Function .NET 6.0 (LTS).***

Iam able to run the migration with your code without issues.

[image]

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***Startup.cs file:***

```cs
using FunctionApp2;
using FunctionApp2.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            _config = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var conn = _config.GetConnectionString("TRY_CXN_String");
            services.AddDbContext<TryDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("TRY_CXN_String")));
        }

    }
}
```

***Migration in Azure Function .NET 6.0 Isolated.***

I have created  `Azure Function 6.0 Isolated`.

Initially even I got the same error when I tried to run the `migration`.

```cs
dotnet ef migrations add FirstMigration
```

[image]

- The problem here is the `Startup.cs` class is not running.
- Instead of `Startup.cs` file, configure the code related to `AddDbContext` (middleware) in `Program.cs` file.

My `Program.cs` file:

```cs
using EntityFramework;
using EntityFramework.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();
        var con = config.GetConnectionString("TRY_CXN_String");
        services.AddDbContext<TryDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));
    })
                .UseConsoleLifetime();

var builder = host.Build();
builder.Run();
```

- Now Iam able to run the migration without any issues.

***Output:***

[image]